# twisted.internet.error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError: reactor already installed

Tags: python, scrapy

I am having this error when I run a crawl process multiples times.
I am using scrapy 2.6
This is my code:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from football.spiders.laliga import LaligaSpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(settings=get_project_settings())
for i in range(1, 29):
    process.crawl(LaligaSpider, **{'week': i})
process.start()
```

Answer (score 7):

For me this worked, I put it before the CrawlerProcess

```py
import sys    
if "twisted.internet.reactor" in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules["twisted.internet.reactor"]
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution avoids use of CrawlerProcess as stated in the docs.
https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script

> There’s another Scrapy utility that provides more control over the crawling process: scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner. This class is a thin wrapper that encapsulates some simple helpers to run multiple crawlers, but it won’t start or interfere with existing reactors in any way.

> It’s recommended you use CrawlerRunner instead of CrawlerProcess if your application is already using Twisted and you want to run Scrapy in the same reactor.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

from football.spiders.laliga import LaligaSpider

# Enable logging for CrawlerRunner
configure_logging()

runner = CrawlerRunner(settings=get_project_settings())
for i in range(1, 29):
    runner.crawl(LaligaSpider, **{'week': i})

deferred = runner.join()
deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

reactor.run()  # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered this problem, but it is solved after updating both Scrapy and Twisted.
the current version of the packages.
Twisted==22.8.0
Scrapy==2.6.2

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into this issue as well. It appears that the docs at https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html are incorrect in stating that CrawlerProcess can be used to run multiple crawlers built with spiders, since each new crawler attempts to load a new reactor instance if you give it a spider. I was able to get my code to work by using CrawlerRunner instead, as also detailed on the same page.

```
import scrapy
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your first spider definition
    ...

class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your second spider definition
    ...

configure_logging()
settings = get_project_settings() # settings not required if running
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)  # from script, defaults provided
runner.crawl(MySpider1) # your loop would go here
runner.crawl(MySpider2)
d = runner.join()
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run() # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
```

Comment: Let me try this! Scrapy should really update their docs

Comment: I can't solve my problem, see my related question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71632249/scrapy-reactoralreadyinstallederror-when-using-twistedscheduler

Comment: Please explain what join() and addBoth() do ?