# Scrapy - ReactorAlreadyInstalledError when using TwistedScheduler

Tags: python, scrapy, twisted, reactor, twisted.internet

I have the following Python code to start APScheduler/TwistedScheduler cronjob to start the spider.

Using one spider was not a problem and worked great. However using two spiders result into the error: `twisted.internet.error.ReactorAlreadyInstalledError: reactor already installed`.

I did found a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71548957/twisted-internet-error-reactoralreadyinstallederror-reactor-already-installed), using `CrawlerRunner` as the solution. However, I'm using TwistedScheduler object, so I do not know how to get this working using multiple cron jobs (multiple `add_job()`).

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from apscheduler.schedulers.twisted import TwistedScheduler

from myprojectscraper.spiders.my_homepage_spider import MyHomepageSpider
from myprojectscraper.spiders.my_spider import MySpider

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
# Start the crawler in a scheduler
scheduler = TwistedScheduler(timezone="Europe/Amsterdam")
# Use cron job; runs the 'homepage' spider every 4 hours (eg. 12:10, 16:10, 20:10, etc.)
scheduler.add_job(process.crawl, 'cron', args=[MyHomepageSpider], hour='*/4', minute=10)
# Use cron job; runs the full spider every week on the monday, tuesday and saturday at 4:35 midnight
scheduler.add_job(process.crawl, 'cron', args=[MySpider], day_of_week='mon,thu,sat', hour=4, minute=35)
scheduler.start()
process.start(False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm now using the [BlockingScheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/schedulers/blocking.html#apscheduler.schedulers.blocking.BlockingScheduler) in combination with `Process` and `CrawlerRunner`. As well as enabling logging via `configure_logging()`.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

from myprojectscraper.spiders.my_homepage_spider import MyHomepageSpider
from myprojectscraper.spiders.my_spider import MySpider

from twisted.internet import reactor

# Create Process around the CrawlerRunner
class CrawlerRunnerProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, spider):
        Process.__init__(self)
        self.runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
        self.spider = spider

    def run(self):
        deferred = self.runner.crawl(self.spider)
        deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
        reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)

# The wrapper to make it run multiple spiders, multiple times
def run_spider(spider):
    crawler = CrawlerRunnerProcess(spider)
    crawler.start()
    crawler.join()

# Enable logging when using CrawlerRunner
configure_logging()

# Start the crawler in a scheduler
scheduler = BlockingScheduler(timezone="Europe/Amsterdam")
# Use cron job; runs the 'homepage' spider every 4 hours (eg. 12:10, 16:10, 20:10, etc.)
scheduler.add_job(run_spider, 'cron', args=[MyHomepageSpider], hour='*/4', minute=10)
# Use cron job; runs the full spider every week on the monday, tuesday and saturday at 4:35 midnight
scheduler.add_job(run_spider, 'cron', args=[MySpider], day_of_week='mon,thu,sat', hour=4, minute=35)
scheduler.start()
```

The script at least doesn't exit directly (it blocks). I now get the following output as expected:

```
2022-03-31 22:50:24 [apscheduler.scheduler] INFO: Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
2022-03-31 22:50:24 [apscheduler.scheduler] INFO: Adding job tentatively -- it will be properly scheduled when the scheduler starts
2022-03-31 22:50:24 [apscheduler.scheduler] INFO: Added job "run_spider" to job store "default"
2022-03-31 22:50:24 [apscheduler.scheduler] INFO: Added job "run_spider" to job store "default"
2022-03-31 22:50:24 [apscheduler.scheduler] INFO: Scheduler started
2022-03-31 22:50:24 [apscheduler.scheduler] DEBUG: Looking for jobs to run
2022-03-31 22:50:24 [apscheduler.scheduler] DEBUG: Next wakeup is due at 2022-04-01 00:10:00+02:00 (in 4775.280995 seconds)
```

Since we are using `BlockingScheduler` the scheduler will not directly exit, but `start()` is a blocking call. Meaning it allows the scheduler to run the jobs infinitely.

Comment: I was using your approach it is starting with 2 spiders but only one reach to the finish stage other spider didn't get finish and after crawling single spider it just sits to the idle state. Any tips?

Comment: @dougj my tip would first to run the two spiders _independently_ without a cronjob.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script

> There’s another Scrapy utility that provides more control over the crawling process: scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner. This class is a thin wrapper that encapsulates some simple helpers to run multiple crawlers, but it won’t start or interfere with existing reactors in any way.
> It’s recommended you use CrawlerRunner instead of CrawlerProcess if your application is already using Twisted and you want to run Scrapy in the same reactor.

https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process

> By default, Scrapy runs a single spider per process when you run scrapy crawl. However, Scrapy supports running multiple spiders per process using the internal API.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from twisted.internet import reactor
from apscheduler.schedulers.twisted import TwistedScheduler

from myprojectscraper.spiders.my_homepage_spider import MyHomepageSpider
from myprojectscraper.spiders.my_spider import MySpider

configure_logging()

runner = CrawlerRunner(get_project_settings())
scheduler = TwistedScheduler(timezone="Europe/Amsterdam")
# Use cron job; runs the 'homepage' spider every 4 hours (eg. 12:10, 16:10, 20:10, etc.)
scheduler.add_job(runner.crawl, 'cron', args=[MyHomepageSpider], hour='*/4', minute=10)
# Use cron job; runs the full spider every week on the monday, tuesday and saturday at 4:35 midnight
scheduler.add_job(runner.crawl, 'cron', args=[MySpider], day_of_week='mon,thu,sat', hour=4, minute=35)

deferred = runner.join()
deferred.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())

scheduler.start()
reactor.run()  # the script will block here until all crawling jobs are finished
scheduler.shutdown()
```

Comment: Thank you. The whole `Queue`, `q.put` and `q.get` are optional right? I use Scrapy middleware to process items.

Comment: Also the `*args` are optional. If you do not pass additional arguments to your spider or the super class (scrapy.Spider).

Comment: Did you test the code? Since it doesn't work. `TwistedScheduler` looks like it doesn't accept `run_spider`. The code is getting executed, but without showing any output of the scheduler. And the scripts basically is done with execution. While the script *should* busy wait for the upcoming cron jobs (the upcoming jobs of `add_job`).

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg Yes, `Queue` and `*args` are optional. And no I haven't tried it with `TwistedScheduler` but the `ReactorAlreadyInstalledError` should be resolved with this.

Comment: Well it doesn't work at all. This doesn't resolve my problem with Twisted Scheduler. Can you give me an actual solution for my question?

Comment: I cleaned up your code and also enabled logging (`configure_logging()`) when using `CrawlerRunner`. But again, I'm still busy to get it working with `TwistedScheduler`

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg I got it working. I'll post another solution

Comment: I'm looking at the `CrawlerProcess` code: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/_modules/scrapy/crawler.html#CrawlerProcess. As you can see they use `reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=False)` as a blocking call. I think we need to use a blocking in the same way in combination with `TwistedScheduler`

Comment: Since we are spawning processes, I use the `BlockingScheduler`. I think this is the way.

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg Try the edited solution. Let me know if it works.

Comment: It doesn't since my jobs are cronjobs that needs to run forever (according to the cronjob specification). Therefor the scheduler should never stop or shutdown. The jobs need to run, for example, every 4 hours until the world end.

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg I tested this code myself. It works too. Anyways, it was good experience answering my first question. Learned a lot. Thank you :)

Comment: Does it keep working forever? Again my cronjob should run every x hours or every x minutes. Try for example: `scheduler.add_job(runner.crawl, 'cron', args=[YourSpider],  minute='*/5')`. Your spider should now be executed every 5 min. if not, your code is not working as expected.

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg Yeah it runs infinitely without any errors. I ran using both 'cron' and 'interval'.

Comment: Owh interesting, but that means that `scheduler.shutdown()` is never called. Ps. See also my other solution  below, using `BlockingScheduler`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try deleting the reactor installed before starting the process:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from apscheduler.schedulers.twisted import TwistedScheduler

from myprojectscraper.spiders.my_homepage_spider import MyHomepageSpider
from myprojectscraper.spiders.my_spider import MySpider
import sys  """<--- import sys here"""

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
# Start the crawler in a scheduler
scheduler = TwistedScheduler(timezone="Europe/Amsterdam")
# Use cron job; runs the 'homepage' spider every 4 hours (eg. 12:10, 16:10, 20:10, etc.)
scheduler.add_job(process.crawl, 'cron', args=[MyHomepageSpider], hour='*/4', minute=10)
# Use cron job; runs the full spider every week on the monday, tuesday and saturday at 4:35 midnight
scheduler.add_job(process.crawl, 'cron', args=[MySpider], day_of_week='mon,thu,sat', hour=4, minute=35)
scheduler.start()

if "twisted.internet.reactor" in sys.modules:
    del sys.modules["twisted.internet.reactor"] """<--- Delete twisted reactor if already installed here """

process.start(False)
```

This was what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to enter the source code for `twisted` and enters the `internet` folder and find `selectedreactor.py`.

Then go to the bottom of the page at `def install` and add the following right above `installReactor(reactor)`

such as:

```
def install():
    """Configure the twisted mainloop to be run using the select() reactor."""
    reactor = SelectReactor()
    from twisted.internet.main import installReactor
    
    if "twisted.internet.reactor" in sys.modules:
        del sys.modules["twisted.internet.reactor"]

    installReactor(reactor)


__all__ = ["install"]
```

This should remove any pre-installed reactors and then install a new one.

This should remove the issue permanently as I have not had any issues yet with this method.